# Retrieve selected values from multi-select box in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a hard time retrieving values from a multi-select box in Vue.  After the user has selected any number of values, I want to retrieve the values and submit to a data source.  No luck so far.  Here's an excerpt of my code below.

```
<div id="app">
   <select multiple v-bind:data-id="program.id" :disabled="!program.editable" v-model="program.dropDowns">
       <option>Microsoft</option>
       <option>IBM</option>
       <option>Google</option>
       <option>Apple</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

```
getPrograms: function() {
      axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs").then((response) => {
          this.programs = response.data.map(row => ({
            ...row,
            dateFormatted: toDDMMYY(row.Date),
            editable: false,
            dropDowns: ["Apple","Google"]
          }));
        console.log(this.programs)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the actual [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/ExxwPOY?editors=1011)

Comment: Where is it that you are submitting the data to a datasource?

Comment: I'm submitting to a list.  I initially posted relevant code but notified me to trim it.

Comment: Oh I see! Let me know if my answer was of any help.

Comment: Actually, it didn't really work. Edit the company column and select more than one value and click save. It's not captureing the values. codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG?editors=1011

Answer (score 2):

Just you have assigned drop down data wrongly , Need to change like below:

Little change in template:

```
<button v-else  @click="saveItem(program)">save</button>
```

and saveItem() method like below:

```
saveItem (program) {
     program.isReadOnly = true
     program.editable = false
     console.log(program)
     alert(program.dropDowns)
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  I thought it was working but that didn't really work.   Edit the company column and select more than one value and click save. 
It's not captureing the values. https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG?editors=1011

Comment: still it is working, but now you have changed your code, as per your current code, you have to change the saveItem method like :   saveItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = true
      console.log(program)
      alert("New Value: "+program.company)
      alert("Previous Value: "+program.company)
    }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not passing anything to the `saveItem` function, so no `program` was being sent.

You just have to replace `saveItem` for `saveItem(program)` and that should do the trick.

Comment: By the way, the part of the code I'm talking about is not written in your post. You should have all your relevant code inside your post, not just in a codepen.

Comment: Right. `<button v-else  @click="saveItem(program)">save</button>`